# CMake: custom target's flags

Tags: cmake

How can I write `CMakeLists.txt` in a way it has two targets `all` (default) and `test`, where `test` target has flags that differ from `all` target's flags. The problem is that when I build libraries for tests I need to link some stuff that shouldn't be in release build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.0)
PROJECT (RootProject)

OPTION(BUILD_TESTING "Build tests." OFF)
IF(BUILD_TESTING)
  # custom compiler option
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-Zc:wchar_t-)
ENDIF(BUILD_TESTING)


ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(Lib1)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(Lib2)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(Lib3)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(Lib4)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(Bin)

IF(BUILD_TESTING)
  # more custom compiler option just for tests
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-Zc:wchar_t-)

  ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(TestLib1)
  ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(TestLib2)
  ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(TestBin)
  MESSAGE( STATUS "Testing folders have been added." )
ENDIF(BUILD_TESTING)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't what I'm looking for. Consider I have two libraries `lib1` and `lib2`. When build `test` target I want this libraries to be built with specific compiler flags, otherwise this libs should be built with other flags.

Comment: how do you set this flag to ON? I managed to change with cmake -i, but is there somehow option to pass on console?

Comment: @BЈовић: [-D <var>:<type>=<value>](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#opt:-Dvar:typevalue)? (`-D BUILD_TESTING:BOOL=TRUE`) I haven't done it for years.